# How to import the Library: Coq.Arith.PeanoNat in Coq?

Tags: coq

I need to use the part of the standard library called Coq.Arith.PeanoNat (https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.html).

I've tried either importing the entire Arith library or just this module, but I can't use it either way.

Every other library I've tried works just fine. When I do `Require Import Bool.` I compile and I can use it correctly. Upon `Print Bool.` I can take a look at all the functions inside in the next format:

```
Module
Bool
:= Struct
Definition...
.
.
.
End
```

When I do either `Require Import Arith.PeanoNat.` or `Require Import Arith.` I get this as immediate output:

```
[Loading ML file z_syntax_plugin.cmxs ... done]
[Loading ML file quote_plugin.cmxs ... done]
[Loading ML file newring_plugin.cmxs ... done]
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been     masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
<W> Grammar extension: in [tactic:simple_tactic], some rule has been masked
```

When I ask Coq `Print Arith.PeanoNat` it outputs: `Module Arith := Struct  End`, it seems to be empty. When I try to use anything from the library, for example `le_le` under boolean comparisons, I get the standard `Error: leb_le not a defined object.` I have updated Coq and the libraries, and I have no idea of what might be going on here. I'd appreciate your input in fixing this library problem.

Comment: Are you importing any other modules at the same time that might cause conflicts?

Comment: @ichistmeinname, I'm only importing Bool and Arith. For testing purposes I imported other ones, and deleted them from my file when I saw they worked just fine.

Answer (score 15):

If I am not mistaken, `Require` is the keyword to load a file.  `Import` has to do with managing name spaces.  Often they are used together, as in `Require Import PeanoNat.`, but they are really doing two different things.

When coq files (`DirName/FileName.vo`) are loaded with `Require`, it is as if the contents of `FileName.vo` is wrapped in `Module DirName.FileName` ... `End.` Everyting defined in the file is then accessed with `DirName.FileName.Name`.

The file can itself have modules `M` inside of it, and to get to `M`'s contents, one has to type `DirName.FileName.ModuleName.Name1` etc.

`Import` is used to get all the definitions up to the top level.  By doing `Import DirName.FileName.ModuleName` the module `Name1` is now imported to the top level, and can be referenced without the long path.

In your example above, the file `Arith/PeanoNat.vo` defines the module `Nat`.  Actually, that is all it defines.  So if you do  `Require Import Arith.PeanoNat` you get `PeanoNat.Nat` at the top level. And then `Import PeanoNat.Nat` will bring `Nat` to the top level. Note that you can't do `Require Import PeanoNat.Nat` because it is no `.vo` file.

Coq can sometimes find a `.vo` file without you having to specify the whole path, so you can also do `Require Import PeanoNat.` and coq will find the file.  If you wonder where it found it, do `Locate PeanoNat.`

```
Coq < Require Import PeanoNat.

Coq < Locate PeanoNat.
Module Coq.Arith.PeanoNat
```

Another `Nat` is also available from another place than `PeanoNat.`

```
Coq < Require Import Nat.
Warning: Notation _ + _ was already used in scope nat_scope
Warning: Notation _ * _ was already used in scope nat_scope
Warning: Notation _ - _ was already used in scope nat_scope

Coq < Locate Nat.
Module Coq.Init.Nat
```

So, you don't `Import` a library, you `Require` it. You use `Import` to not have to use the full path name.  I hope this helps you debug what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I think I won't have issues importing anymore.

Comment: @Sara If this answer resolves your issue, a nice thing to do is to accept the answer.

Comment: This answer is the closest to my issue, so I post a question here: I first type `Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NDiv.` Then command `Print NDiv.` returns `Module NDiv := Struct Module Type NDivProp End`, command `Print NDivProp` prints a list of lemmas, one of which I want to use. But `Import NDivProp.` throws an error `NDivProp is not a module`, `Print add_mod` (the lemma I want to use) throws an error `Error: add_mod not a defined object.`, commands `NDiv.add_mod`, `NDivProp.add_mod`, `NDivProp.NDiv.add_mod` also print errors. So how to access the `add_mod` lemma?

Comment: I think the preferred way on SO is to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When I try `Print Arith.PeanoNat`, the output is slightly different: I get `Module PeanoNat := Struct Module Nat End` and then even though `leb_le` is not in scope, `Nat.leb_le` is.

(I run `8.5beta2` in case that's relevant).

Comment: I think it does make the difference. I tried checking if Nat.leb_le as well, and I get the same "not a defined object".

Comment: Hi @gallais. Somehow, Nat.leb_le is in scope now (I only closed coq for the day, when I tried running the same file again today it was working better...), but I'm still having issues. I have that Nat.leb_le is scope. How can I now use, on a proof? "apply leb_le" yields "Te reference leb_le was not found in current environment"

Comment: @Sara Great news! If `leb_le` is not in scope but `Nat.leb_le` is then you have to either use the long name `Nat.leb_le` or `Import Nat` first in order to bring its content (including `leb_le`) into scope (cf. [the bit of the manual about modules](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#hevea_command54)).

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! I realised I was also importing things in the wrong order (I was not aware that it would make a difference!). Now everything seems to be running.